# error while trying to generate stub file

Tags: java, rmi, stub

When i try to generate a stub file using :`rmic RemoteMethodImpl`
I get the following error :

```
error: File .\RemoteMethodImpl.class does not contain type RemoteMethodImpl as expected, but type InterfaceImplementation.RemoteMethodImpl. Please remove the file, or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the class path.
error: Class RemoteMethodImpl not found.
2 errors
```

What error is this ? Why do i get this ?

*Upon the request of  @ Shashank Kadne*

```
package InterfaceImplementation;
import Interfaces.RemoteMethodIntf;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import Design.Main_Design_Client;
/**
 *
 * @author program-o-steve
 */
 public class RemoteMethodImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RemoteMethodIntf{
  public RemoteMethodImpl() throws Exception{}   

@Override
public void send(String IP,String Message) throws RemoteException {
  Main_Design_Client mdc = new Main_Design_Client();
  mdc.jTextArea1.setText("<html><b>Message from :</b></html>" + IP);
  mdc.jTextArea1.setText("<html><b>Message :</b></html>" + Message);
}
```

}

Comment: Does it extends UnicastRemoteObject ? Also, try setting the classpath just before executing rmic.

Comment: Can you please upload your RemoteMethodImpl.java  ?

Comment: @ Shashank Kadne see the edit

Comment: From which folder you are excecuting rmic command ?.. from Within InterfaceImplementation folder or from outside the InterfaceImplementation folder ??

Comment: see my answer...it should work..

Comment: You haven't needed to generate RIM stubs for about 7-1/2 years. See the preamble to the Javadoc for UnicastRemoteObject, and the JDK 1.5 RMI Release Notes.

Comment: Also related to this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61808689/6648326

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming you are in a directory just outside "InterfaceImplementation" folder.

Execute : `rmic InterfaceImplementation.RemoteMethodImpl`

Comment: yeah that works ! But can you explain why i couldn't get one when i compiled from inside ?

Comment: Its because the classes named in the rmic command must be classes that have been compiled successfully with the javac command and must be fully package qualified. Here, your RemoteMethodImpl was actually inside package InterfaceImplementation. So it gave you the exception while executing "rmic RemoteMethodImpl"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I was trying

```
% rmic GumballMachine
```

but changed after reading it from

```
% rmic gumball\GumballMachine
```

to

```
%rmic gumball.GumballMachine
```

which works fine. Sometimes, I wonder what a blockhead I am!!

Answer (score 0):

> When i try to generate a stub file

Stop right there. You haven't needed to do that for about eight years.

> public RemoteMethodImpl() throws Exception{}

Just change that to call `super()` and you won't need a stub at all. See the preamble to the Javadoc for `java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject`.