# rmic error class not found

Tags: java, rmi

I'm reading head first java and I'm about to try the ready baked codes that shows how to use RMI.
These are the classes:

The remote interface

```
import java.rmi.*;

public interface MyRemote extends Remote {

    public String sayHello() throws RemoteException;
}
```

The remote implementation

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public class MyRemoteImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements MyRemote {

    public String sayHello() {
        return "Server Says,Hello";
    }

    public MyRemoteImpl() throws RemoteException { }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            MyRemote service = new MyRemoteImpl();
            Naming.rebind("Remote Hello", service);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I placed the .java and the .class file in c:\RMI. When running it, it says MyRemoteImpl class not found even though I'm running from the same directory. How can i fix this? Thanks.

EDIT: The error appear when I try to run this command

```
rmic MyRemoteImpl
```

Comment: What the heck is answer to this? How did you resolve it? I'm facing the same issue and don't wanna start a new thread for that.

Comment: If you trying this inside a Maven project, then classes are placed in the target folder. Run the rmic command from there. That leads to another problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275782/error-while-trying-to-generate-stub-file

Answer (score 2):

The comments of BuddingProgrammer worked for my as well.

For instance if your classes are in folder C:\users\renato\workspace\ADI\src\semana5 you should go to one level above:
C:\users\renato\workspace\ADI\src and you should compile like this: javac semana5\Calculadora.java

To run RMI you should type the following command in `C:\users\renato\workspace\ADI\src`:

```
 rmic semana5.CalculadoraImp
```

Comment: This is only true if the Java classes are in a package called `semana5`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not running this command from the directory containing the .class file, you should be, assuming there is no package statement as per what you posted. If there's a package statement you should be running this command from the directory that contains the highest-level package.

Otherwise there's something wrong with your CLASSPATH environment variable. It should at least contain ".", probably some other stuff as well. As a workaround you can adopt Isaac's suggestion but then you'll only get the same problem when you come to compile and execute.

Comment: Whether you edit your CLASSPATH environment variable to always contain a "." or not, depends on your usage pattern. Some people prefer to avoid system-wide compile-time definitions, others welcome them. Then again, most people don't manually compile from the command line. I'd actually consider the CLASSPATH environment variable approach to be a "workaround", but that's just my taste.

Comment: @Isaac The alternative implies having to specify -classpath . on every Java command line tool? javac, java, javap, javah, keytool, jar, jarsigner, idlj, ... Not very attractive. Most of these are embedded in IDEs, sure, but not all of them.

Comment: As I wrote, it depends on your usage pattern. If one is to mainly use the command-line to compile and execute code, then yes, the CLASSPATH environment variable is certainly handy. If one is generally using IDE's to compile and execute code, then the CLASSPATH variable is yet another setting that is (for the most part) meaningless and therefore should be avoided (if there's no reason for it, why do it?).

Comment: The reason I downvoted your answer, by the way, is that your answer covered a concern that wasn't really raised by the asker. The asker has asked why rmic can't find his classes. The short answer is that it's a classpath issue. You mentioned that there's "something wrong with your CLASSPATH environment variable", which is simply incorrect. How can you determine, for a user, whether their CLASSPATH environment variable is correct or not, if you don't know much about their typical usage pattern of compilation tools?

Comment: @Isaac I've given the reason. IDEs don't cover every Java command line tool.

Comment: I repeat: **depending on your usage**. There's no "one size fits all" here. You know what, that could possibly be an interesting debate, but on another S.O topic.

Comment: @Isaac My CLASSPATH has contained '.' since 1997 and I have never put it there. Ergo Java puts it there, ergo if it isn't there somebody has messed with the OP's CASSPATH, which is 100% sufficient to account for the OP's problem. The answer is therefore not incorrect. My answer also includes a positive reference to your own answer, so you are therefore downvoting your own answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a folder name it `HelloServer`
2. Add a this package `package HelloServer;` on the top of each class, `MyRemote` and `MyRemoteImpl`.
3. Open cmd and write `javac HelloServer/MyRemote.java` and `javac HelloServer/MyRemoteImpl.java` from the directory that contain the `HelloServer` folder.
4. Write `rmic HelloServer.MyRemoteImpl` from the directory that contain the `HelloServer` folder.
5. You should have now a `MyRemoteImpl_stub.class` and you can have a nice day :)

PS: It is important that the package name is different than RMI or any object used inside the class. Otherwise you will have object collision.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had the same problem and none of these answers helped me, I'll add what worked for me. I was running rmic MyRemoteImpl in the directory that contained MyRemoteImpl.java and got the same error. When I ran rmic MyRemoteImpl in the directory that contained MyRemoteImpl.class, it worked and created MyRemoteImpl_Stub.class. I did not need to set CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0):

if the class is located in C:/../src/Assign/implement.class then

1. change your directory in cmd by entering:- cd C:/....../src
2. run the command:- rmic Assign.implement.class

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have the same code, but in a Maven project. First step is to compile all the code with `mvn compile`. Note that all compiled classes (ex.MyRemoteImpl in this case) are stored in the target folder in your maven project.

The next step is to `cd to \target\classes` folder.

Finally, run the rmic command with the fully qualified name of the target class, i.e with the packages of the class - `rmic my_package1.my_sub_package.MyRemoteImpl`.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm about 8 years too late, but just for anyone else in the future who might come across this same problem, the following worked for me:

In the folder that contains your files, first start off with `javac *.java` and then proceed with the `rmic class_name` step. This should generate the stub.

Answer (score 0):

- There is a path variable called `CLASSPATH` where the JVM will look for **class** files to excute when you try to run a **class** file.
- **CLASSPATH** describes the location where all the required files are available which are used in the application.
- Java Compiler and JVM (Java Virtual Machine) use **CLASSPATH** to locate the required files.
- If the **CLASSPATH** is not set, Java Compiler will not be able to find the required files and hence will throw error.
- If you don't know where your current path is, then type `echo "%CLASSPATH%"` in the command prompt.
- Alternatively, you can also add/remove/edit the `CLASSPATH` variable in the **Environmental Variables**.
- Make sure that you have added your **Java** to your path.
- To add the current path where your `.class` files exists there are three ways.

  1. Using **Environmental variables** - [Reference](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-set-classpath-in-java)
  2. Using **Command Prompt** - `set PATH = .`
  3. Specify the class path using `-classpath` argument while executing.
- **Semi-colon (`;`)** is used as a separator and **dot (`.`)** is the default value of **CLASSPATH** while specifying the class path using `-classpath` argument.

```
rmic -classpath . <Class Name>
```

```
rmic -classpath "C:\Example\Demo" <Class Name>
```

- Here `.` stands for the current directory and you can specify any path there.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding:

```
-classpath .
```

By default, rmic's classpath is derived from the CLASSPATH environment variable (thanks EJP for the correction).

Comment: No it isn't. See the Tool Documentation. By default rmic's classpath comes from the CLASSPATH environment variable, which should certainly always contain '.'.

Comment: "Should certainly always contain '.'"? I severely doubt that.